# What is the error called when a letter of an abbreviation is spelled out afterwards?

Tags: abbreviations, redundancy, errors

> HI***V*** Virus
>
> DN***S*** System
>
> IR***C*** Chat
>
> LC***D*** Display
>
> R***A***ID Array

These are some examples for this and people do this quite often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also as in PIN Number. This is often known as RAS Syndrome - a linguistic joke since the RAS stands for "Redundant Acronym Syndrome" thus illustrating the fault it describes in the repetition of "Syndrome". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome?wprov=sfla1

Comment: And where do you use your PIN Number?  At the ATM Machine, of course.